# Connections between Map, Reduce operations and Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I am interested with `Map` and `Reduce` operations in computer science. I would like to do analogies with Mathematics and especially with Linear Algebra.

1. Reduce

First, could we say that "`Reduce`" operation can be translated as a linear form, ie I start from a vector and I get a scalar from the coordinates of the initial vector ?

But a linear form is by definition linear, is it always the case for Reduction in computer science ?

2. Map

Secondly, could we say that "`Map`" can be translated as an endomorphism, i.e we start from an initial vector (like a list in computer science) and we get also a vector as output.

If I take "`Map`" operation, and `f` a function, I have :

$f[x_{1}, x_{2} ..., x_{n}] = [ f(x_{1}), f(x_{2}), ..., f(x_{n})]$

I could write it like this :

$f[\vec{X}] = f [\sum_{i=1}^{n}\,x_{i}\,\vec{e_{i}}]= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\,x_{i}\,\vec{f(e_{i})}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\,x_{i}\,F_{ij}\,\vec{e_{j}}=[f(x_{1}), f(x_{2}), ..., f(x_{n})]$

So I get : $f(x_{j})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\,F_{ij}\,x_{i}$ with $F_{ij}$ called the matrix of change basis of the `endomorphism "f"`

But I don't get this relation above, well known between a change of basis (Matrix $F_{ij}$) and coordinates into 2 basis :

$x_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\,F_{ij}\,x'_{i}$

Moreover, the function "f(x)" is not necessary a linear function, this could be another classical function like cosinus or exponential.

I don't know how to make correct connections between Linear algebra and "Map,Reduce" operations ?

If someone could help to Conceptualize these operations, this would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: The analogy isn't really there. Map is vector to vector (of the same size), but it needn't be a nice kind of mapping. Reduce is usually vector to scalar, but again it needn't be a nice kind of mapping. That said, matrix multiplication is a kind of map: if you interpret $B$ as an array of column vectors, $AB$ is what you get when you map $A$ (understood as a map from vectors to vectors) over that array of column vectors.

Comment: The challenge with making direct analogies to linear algebra is that map and reduce can be quite general operations.  However, in some cases it may be possible.  For example, one type of reduction is to sum all the elements.  This can be thought of as taking a dot product with the all 1's vector (resulting in the scalar sum).  However, the result of a Reduce need not be a scalar.